# Migrating a moodle site in windows

Tags: windows, migration, moodle

Seasonal greetings to you all,

I'm new to moodle and have created a moodle site (version 3.3.2) on a local windows 7 machine. I now have to demo the site to 30 students as part of my final project at uni. How do I migrate the site from a windows machine to say a virtual windows machine that the student can all access?

Moodles own site seems to just cater for Linux machines so its not much help

Answer (score 0):

While the command line examples may be Linux specific, the steps on https://docs.moodle.org/34/en/Moodle_migration are relevant whatever your OS

```
1.1 Turn on maintenance mode *(front end UI)*
1.2 Backup the Moodle database on the old sever *(can be done in phpmyadmin or mysqlworkbench or whatever other relevant database management software you use and depending on the database you are using)*
1.3 Restore the database backup to the new server *(as above)*
1.4 Copy moodledata from the old server to the new server *(while rsync is a useful tool, this can be done with any copy/paste tool or ftp etc - just be prepared to take time if you are copying between servers or via an external medium)*
1.5 Copy the Moodle code from the old server to the new server *(as above - copy/ftp or just reinstall the code and then copy your config.php)*
1.6 Update config.php with the URL of the new server 
1.7 Test the copied site
1.8 Update links containing wwwroot in the database *(you may want to do this as part of the migration above - using a search and replace on the text of the export before re-importing it)*
1.9 Take the site out of maintenance mode
```